# Using results from a query paired with a case statement to assign an output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to determine how to build in the following logic. I have the following query with the following output. I am trying to add in logic that will assign a station size for the year based on the four instances of the size out put of the individual weeks. For example, if a station outputs ds small at wk 16,sa small at wk 20, ds small at wk 40, and ds standard at wk 48 then I want to assign ds small to that station. I have around 300 uses of logic like this I want to map in. I would assume to use a case statement but not quite sure how to manipulate the query.

```
SELECT 
    station,
    ISNULL(ar, '0') AS dsar,
    del_date,
    SUM(volume) / 7 AS volume_ref,
    DATE_PART("week", del_date) AS week_num,
    DATE_PART("year", del_date) AS year,
    CASE 
        WHEN volume_ref BETWEEN 0 AND 20000 AND dsar <> 'YES' 
            THEN 'ds x-small'
        WHEN volume_ref BETWEEN 20000 AND 36000 AND dsar <> 'YES' 
            THEN 'ds small'
        WHEN volume_ref BETWEEN 36000 AND 42000 AND dsar <> 'YES'    
            THEN 'ds standard'
        WHEN volume_ref BETWEEN 42000 AND 72000 AND dsar <> 'YES' 
            THEN 'ds large'
        WHEN volume_ref > 72000 
            THEN 'ds x-large'
        WHEN dsar = 'YES' 
            THEN 'ds x-large'
        ELSE 'ds small' 
    END AS station_ref
FROM 
    prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp
LEFT JOIN 
    wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute ON prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp.station = wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds 
WHERE
    week_num IN (16, 20, 40, 48)
GROUP BY 
    na_topology_lrp.station, raw_station_extended_attribute.ar,
    na_topology_lrp.del_date;
```

[image]

Comment: `case` _expression_, not statement...

Comment: what exactly do you need as output it is not so clear

Comment: I want to assign a station size to each station based on the four output of weeks 16,20,40,and 48. So based of what a station gets assigned in those four weeks I only assign one station size for the year. This is because there are fluctuations in volume throughout the year and I am trying to assign a station size that will best suit it over the course of a year.

Comment: You apparently need to aggregate the four values. That's the part of the logic that's missing from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a seperate table that contains the STARTING value and an ENDING value, this table would also contain the STATION_REF designation if the volume_ref falls between the STARTING and ENDING values.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NewTable(  <-- name it what you want..
 Starting DECIMAL(12,3) NOT NULL,
 Ending DECIMAL(12,3) NOT NULL,
 StationRef VARECHAR(50) NOT NULL)
```

To add a row into this table:

```
INSERT dbo.NewTable(Starting,Ending,StationRef)
SELECT 100,199, 'xyz'

INSERT dbo.NewTable(Starting,Ending,StationRef)
SELECT 200,299, 'abc'
```

This is just an example, if you needed PK or other columns you would surely add them.

Then you could simply change your CASE into a SUBSELECT, something like this:

```
SELECT 
station,
ISNULL(ar, '0') AS dsar,
del_date,
SUM(volume) / 7 AS volume_ref,
DATE_PART("week", del_date) AS week_num,
DATE_PART("year", del_date) AS year,
(SELECT NT.StationRef FROM NewTable WHERE volume_ref BETWEEN NT.Starting AND NT.Ending FROM NewTable) AS [StationRef]
FROM 
prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp
LEFT JOIN 
wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute ON prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp.station 
= wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds 
WHERE
week_num IN (16, 20, 40, 48)
GROUP BY 
  na_topology_lrp.station, raw_station_extended_attribute.ar,
na_topology_lrp.del_date;
```

This would provide you a mechanism to change the ranges and designations, data-driven.

**You could make this table in a sproc, a temp table or a table var or CTE in a SELECT statement**

Data driven is still easier than building uber CASE expressions and this table can be built on the fly if needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is ssue is the system is closely guarded so it takes up to 4 weeks to get a table added to our system so I am trying to use this query in the meantime, is there to make a table within this query where I can added the info for example here would be one of the following pieces of logic. if a ds has ds small in wk 16, ds small in wk 20, ds small in wk 40, and ds standard in wk 48 then ds small

Comment: you could make this table in a sproc, a temp table or a table var or CTE

Comment: Thank you do you have a recommendation on how to add this is, I am pretty new to sql.